# Plot colour in Julia

Tags: julia

I am starting to learn Juliabox. I have a question about differentiating colour in Julia plot, based on feature value.
data is:

> x = [2,4,3,5,3,2,1,5,6,4,3]
>
> m = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1]
>
> y = [23,32,43,23,12,54,34,43,56,76,34]

I want to plot points x-y and differentiate the point color based on value m.

I tried :

```
using PyPlot
plot(x,y,".",  color=m)
```

and it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
PyPlot.scatter(x,y,c=m)
```